# Combine two grep commands to process input from a file or grep lines starting with one specific substring and contain another after

Tags: bash, grep

I have a file that i want to pars using grep command,
the file consist of lines like this:

```
NVO,0,267,61,247357,247357,O,19:00:00.000000,06:09:08.417320,07:55:22.068670
DVD,0,267,61,247357,247357,O,19:00:00.000000,06:09:08.417320,07:55:22.068670
NVO,0,267,61,247358,247358,B,19:00:00.000000,06:09:08.417407,07:55:22.079291
DVD,0,267,61,247358,247358,B,19:00:00.000000,06:09:08.417407,07:55:22.079291
```

I want to get only the line that start with NVO, and have ,B, in the line.
the out put should look like this:

```
NVO,0,267,61,247358,247358,B,19:00:00.000000,06:09:08.417407,07:55:22.079291
```

to get the `NVO,` line I'm using `grep ^NVO, file_name.txt`  but I'm unable to add the second condition `,B,`
I tried `grep  '^NVO,|,B,' file_name.txt` and also

```
grep ",B," | grep "^NVO," file_name.txt
```

with no luck
I know I can do it with two commands, the first to write to file and then to do a second grep command with the `,B,` filter

Comment: Use `grep "^NVO,.*,B,"`

Comment: Pass the input filename to the _first_ copy of grep in the pipeline. Only `grep` instances that aren't passed a filename try to read their stdin, and thus see prior pipeline components' output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operation you're attempting does not actually require combining two `grep` calls. Therefore, you can use

```sh
grep "^NVO,.*,B," file > outfile
```

*Details*:

- `^` - string start
- `NVO,` - an `NVO,` string
- `.*` - any text (any zero or more chars)
- `,B,` - a `,B,` text.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/4DixGY):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='NVO,0,267,61,247357,247357,O,19:00:00.000000,06:09:08.417320,07:55:22.068670
DVD,0,267,61,247357,247357,O,19:00:00.000000,06:09:08.417320,07:55:22.068670
NVO,0,267,61,247358,247358,B,19:00:00.000000,06:09:08.417407,07:55:22.079291
DVD,0,267,61,247358,247358,B,19:00:00.000000,06:09:08.417407,07:55:22.079291'
grep "^NVO,.*,B," <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
NVO,0,267,61,247358,247358,B,19:00:00.000000,06:09:08.417407,07:55:22.079291
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding this for folks who actually have a good reason to combine two separate `grep` calls -- [the answer by Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70005625/14122) is appropriate in your case, where you don't.

---

The problem here is that your last copy of `grep` is completely ignoring the input from the first one, because you're passing it a filename to read -- so it reads the file and ignores the prior instance. (Also, you aren't telling the first grep where to get input from, so it's reading from stdin).

You can fix that by passing the filename to the *first* component of the pipeline:

```
grep ",B," input_file | grep "^NVO," >output_file
```

...or passing the input file as stdin:

```
<input_file grep ',B,' | grep '^NVO,' >output_file
```

Alternately, if you want to treat both `grep`s as a unit, and pass their stdin and stdout at the end, you can do that:

```
{ grep ',B,' | grep '^NVO,'; } <input_file >output_file
```